# Webgrid: URL for Sorting and Filtering

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, sorting, filter, webgrid

I have a webgrid that is in a partialview. The parial view contains an ajax form which pass data to the webgrid. My view looks like

```
using (Ajax.Begin("Gain", "Gaining", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="Res"}))
{

}
<div id="Res">
  <div id="grid">
     @{var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.myList, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 25, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid",
                        canSort: true);
    grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All));
    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(columnName: "num", header: "Number"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "name", header: "Full Name", canSort: true)
     ));
   }
   </div>
</div>
```

The page displays wells but sorting and moving to the next page does not work. When I try, the grid just dissapears. I notice that when I hover over the column header, that when I hover over the header sorting links, the url is still localhost:XXXXX/#. When I remove the `ajaxUpdateContainerId="Res"`, the url seems right:  localhost:xxx?length=4?sort=name&sortdir=ASC, which is a wrong URL given that my data is obtained from the controller, Gaining and method, Gain

How can I get this to work please.Or how can i debug this? How does sorting works?

**EDIT**

I am now confused as to the use of ajaxUpdateContainerId. According to [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1882472.aspx/1), this did not aid his/her sorting. If I remove it from mine, the whole partial view is removed when I click the header link to sort, or any paging link. What is the use of ajaxUpdateContainerId use then?